# How should i save my app data in my android app?

Tags: java, android, stream, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am making my first android app. I want to save an array of strings in one activity and then in second activity i want to show those strings as a list. I am using android platform 2.2 with API 8 So i can not use putStringSet(). Is there any way to save my data as a text file in my app? Then may be i can just add a new line in that file whenever user adds a new string. And while making list view i can parse it on basis of new line and make string array. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use File Handling.
Easy to use for beginners and efficient for your purpose.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: i used that internal storage. but everytime i write something in file, it removes the old data. i want old data as well

Comment: You are opening the file in the wrong file mode. You are creating a new file everytime, truncating all the old saved data. Open it in the APPEND mode, your data will surely be retained.

Comment: FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);

Answer (score 2):

There is a method `putStringArrayListExtra("id", ArrayList list)` in Intent to use before starting it. Then in the launched Activity from the Intent, use `getStringArrayList("id")`.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("id", yourArrayList)
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Then on NewActivity onCreate() method

```
ArrayList<String> list = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("id");
```

Comment: This String arraylist should be like user history. Whatever user will do should be saved and then showed in list. In this way we will send an array list which will be created before that intent. what about if we have some old strings as well which user has created. how can we fetch that ?

Comment: Then you should write the text to a file, then parse it into an ArrayList, and pass it around like you want.

Answer (score 0):

But you can use putStringArray, or putStringArrayList wrapped into a Bundle.

Bundle are passed via Intents.

-> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putStringArray(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Then, if you want to save it as a file, then you have to use this method : http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/13852-saving-arraylist-file.html

But i think you prefer pass the String list directly.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using files for that?
Just check sharedPreferences and sqliteDb
It may work for you..shared preferences are easy to handle

Comment: i didnt try sqliteDb. but i checked sharedPreferences. In my case sharedPreferences is not a good solution.